# How to use stash:parse and no_results

Tags: stash, no-results

It seems many users have issues with Stash and `no_results`, but as far as I can tell, nobody is trying to do this scenario. Please forgive me if I missed something.

I would like to redirect users to a page if they stumble on the URL for a specific entry for which they do not have permissions, determined by some custom fields specified in `{lv_permissions}`. To make permissions work, I needed to wrap the entries block in `exp:stash:parse process="end"`, but that seems to have killed my `{if no_results}{redirect="site/1"}{/if}` line. No redirect occurs, though the content also does not show up, which is good.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior and some proper syntax?

```
{lv_permissions}
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
  {exp:channel:entries
    channel="my_channel"
    require_entry="yes"
    limit="1"
    {stash:permissions}
  }
    {if no_results}{redirect="site/1"}{/if}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

I tried the `no_results_prefix` concept, but that doesn’t seem to work for `exp:stash:parse`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found if I repeat the `no_results` line, the redirect works. If I just write it once, no redirect occurs, though the content also does not show up, which is good.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

Navigating to a URL I should not have access to as a logged in user redirects me to /site/1 using this:

```
{lv_permissions}
{exp:stash:parse process="end"}
  {exp:channel:entries
    channel="my_channel"
    require_entry="yes"
    limit="1"
    {stash:permissions}
  }
    {if no_results}{/if}
    {if no_results}{redirect="site/1"}{/if}
  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:parse}
```

This works, but clearly it’s wonky.

Comment: sad but true, thx for this hack - working for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you should rethink your approach a bit here. Whilst it's probably possible to cobble together some esoteric convoluted template code to deal with permissions, it would be much safer and more maintainable if you built a custom add-on to handle your exact needs.

Specifically, you could build an extension based on the channel_entries_tagdata_end hook that makes the necessary checks and redirects accordingly.

Comment: Hi there, I started to explore this option, but ran into problems because I need this to work two ways. The above example is on individual entry pages for redirecting, but I also have search results pages that relies on the same technique to filter out entries user shouldn't see. I can't seem to find a way to use an extension to filter the full result set of a channel:entries tag and return a possibly reduced number of entries. Do you have any pointers for this? Much appreciated!